# Typing a tuple destructuring in a svelte each loop

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am using Typescript `--strict` and would like to annotate types in a svelte `#each` loop. Imagine something like this:

```
 {#each data as [foo, bar], i}
```

It seems like

```
 {#each data as [foo, bar]: [string[], boolean[]], i}
```

should work (those are the types of foo and bar respectively, but Typescript complains that the syntax is not correct. I'll likely approach the problem differently which will obviate this question, but I am curious now how to type a destructured tuple at the point of destructuring.

Comment: does the code work without adding types? you shouldn't need to put types there since `data` should already be typed

Comment: @Samathingamajig, thanks for responding so quickly. It doesn't get past Typescript --strict check because the resulting destructured local vars then have type any. So it may work, but I'd have to temporarily disable --strict to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessors are currently [not applied](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4701) to expressions within the template. If your data is typed correctly in the script block, there will be no need to type the items inline. In this case `[string[], boolean[]][]`.

If data has to be typed differently for whatever reason, you could try to use a reactive statement to apply a type assertion.

E.g.

```js
$: dataTyped = data as [string[], boolean[]][];
```

Comment: I like your idea of a reactive statement. Thank you, I'll try that. Thanks for the link to the proposal too, that is something I have been wondering about. This situation is actually a result of the idea behind that proposal not being implemented. It can be difficult to write referentially transparent code with things the way they are now. The current state of affairs tends to push code to need to do side effecting in functions within the script tag so that those side effected "component global" vars are available in the template.

Comment: If templates were more capable we could write more functional svelte code, but as is, various template structures are quite limited, disallowing typing and also things like derived values as bindable targets, etc..